# How to get Excel(csv) to properly display special characters

Tags: python, excel, csv, char

I'm trying to eliminate non-UTF8 chars from a csv in Windows, does anyone know the equivalent of the following command for windows:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c
```

I can't get Excel(csv file) to properly display special characters, I have tried opening with txt(Notepad -using ‘UTF-8’/‘UTF-8 with BOM’ encoding) but without success.

Type of characters:
[image]

```
with open(hardware_interface.csv', 'rb') as rawdata:
result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(30000))

print(result)
```

output: {'encoding': 'UTF-8-SIG', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}

```
for col in df.columns:
                if df[col].dtype == object:
                    df[col] = df[col].apply(
                        lambda x: np.nan if x == np.nan else str(x).encode('utf-8-sig', 'replace').decode('utf-8-sig'))
```

Still, nothing changes

Comment: When importing data from a text file (e.g., a CSV file) you can specify the encoding used to write the said text file. Have you tried that or are you just double-clicking on the CSV file and letting Excel guess the encoding?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel of course, I have tried this way from excel, importing data from txt file and choose 65001: Unicode (UTF-8). I have also tried to not open the csv directly but using notepad first with the specific encoding but without any result.

Comment: Then perhaps your file is not even UTF-8. Try some other encodings.

Comment: Converting with `iconv` requires that you use the correct input encoding.

Comment: Is that Japanese, Chinese, or Korean? Or does your file contain a mix of languages?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel it should be information in English, however, it  is displayed this way. I'm updating the description with some line of code I used but again, with no result. It seems to be utf-8-sig but when using the code, nothing changes

Comment: Without examining the data, we are all just guessing.  If it's supposed to be in English, and it is displaying as Asian language like characters, there's probably an encoding issue or a corrupt file. (Or maybe not really in English!) You might be able to examine the file with a Hex Editor and figure out what's going on that way.

Comment: If it is supposed to be in English then I suspect your file is seriously hosed. But have a try with [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) and see if it can determine the actual encoding but I haven't encountered an encoding that would turn English into what you've shown.